# Rotate chart dygraphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Sorry for my English. How to rotate the chart 90deg using the latest version of the dygraphs. I managed to rotate the graph and zoom functionality using this version of https://dygraphs.com/1.1.0-rc/download.html, but from some version of the dygraphs they stopped supporting interactionModel: mouseup, mousemove, mouseout. What to replace? Thank you in advance!
My example on version 1.1.0:

```js
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }

  var arr = [];
  var step = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
    arr[i] = [step += 0.025, getRndInteger(50, 100)];
  }


  $(function () {
    dygraph_show('#graph', arr);
  });


  function dygraph_show(dygraph_div_id, data) {
    var dygraph_width = 500;
    var dygraph_height = 150;

    // change the dygraph interaction model for this graph so we can properly interact with a graph which is rotated 90 degrees. Basically, we need to switch mouse X and mouse Y values
    var newInteraction = function (c, b, a) {
      // 'c' is the MouseEvent, and we need to change the X and Y values.
      // However, the MouseEvent object is read-only, so we need to make a new MouseEvent based on the values of the old one.
      var new_c;
      if (document.createEvent) new_c = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
      else if (document.createEventObject) new_c = document.createEventObject();

      // switch the x and y values for this mouse event by copying the old mouse event and inserting new x & y values, based on the position of the dygraph.
      // Dygraphs doesn't make use of screenX and screenY, so we can ignore those
      var new_x = c.pageY + $(dygraph_div_id).offset().left - $(dygraph_div_id).offset().top; // vertical
      var new_y = $(dygraph_div_id).height() + $(dygraph_div_id).offset().top - (c.pageX - $(dygraph_div_id).offset().left) - $(window).scrollTop()+68; // horizontal

      new_c.initMouseEvent(c.type, c.bubbles, c.cancelable, c.view, c.detail, c.screenX, c.screenY, new_x, new_y, c.ctrlKey, c.altKey, c.shiftKey, c.metaKey, c.button, c.target);


      // call the original function, but with the new altered MouseEvent
      Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel[c.type](new_c, b, a);
    };

    // the 'restyle' function rotates and repositions all the labels so as to be readable once again.
    var restyle = function () {
      var xlabel_transform = 'rotate(180deg) translateY(-5px) rotateY(180deg)';
      $(dygraph_div_id + ' .dygraph-xlabel').parent().css({
        transform: xlabel_transform,
        msTransform: xlabel_transform,
        webkitTransform: xlabel_transform
      });

      var ylabel_transform = 'rotate(90deg) rotateY(180deg) translateY(-10px)';
      $(dygraph_div_id + ' .dygraph-ylabel').parent().css({
        transform: ylabel_transform,
        msTransform: ylabel_transform,
        webkitTransform: ylabel_transform
      });

      //var axis_label_x_transform = 'translateY(17.5px) translateX(0.5px) rotate(90deg) rotateY(180deg)';
      var axis_label_x_transform = 'translateY(17.5px) translateX(0.5px) rotate(-90deg)';
      $(dygraph_div_id + ' .dygraph-axis-label-x, ' + dygraph_div_id + ' .dygraph-axis-label-y').parent().css({
        transform: axis_label_x_transform,
        msTransform: axis_label_x_transform,
        webkitTransform: axis_label_x_transform
      });

      //var axis_label_y_transform = 'translateX(17.5px) translateY(0.5px) rotate(90deg) rotateY(180deg)';
      var axis_label_y_transform = 'translateX(17.5px) translateY(0.5px) rotate(-90deg)';
      $(dygraph_div_id + ' .dygraph-axis-label-y').parent().css({
        transform: axis_label_y_transform,
        msTransform: axis_label_y_transform,
        webkitTransform: axis_label_y_transform
      });

      $(dygraph_div_id + ' .dygraph-legend').css({
        textAlign: 'right',
        top: '125px',
        left: (dygraph_width - 125) + 'px'
      });
    };

    // set rotation and position of dygraph div
    //var dygraph_transform = 'rotate(-90deg) rotateX(180deg) translateX(' + (dygraph_height - dygraph_width)/2 + 'px) translateY(' + (dygraph_width - dygraph_height)/2 + 'px)';
    var dygraph_transform = 'rotate(90deg) translateX(' + (dygraph_height + dygraph_width) / 6 + 'px) translateY(' + (dygraph_width - dygraph_height) / 2 + 'px)';
    $(dygraph_div_id).css({
      transform: dygraph_transform,
      msTransform: dygraph_transform,
      webkitTransform: dygraph_transform
    });

    // set the options for the dygraph
    var dygraph_options = {
      width: dygraph_width,
      height: dygraph_height,
      axes: {
        x: {pixelsPerLabel: 30},
        y: {pixelsPerLabel: 30}
      },
      interactionModel: {
        willDestroyContextMyself: true,
        mousedown: newInteraction,
        mouseup: newInteraction,
        mousemove: newInteraction,
        mouseout: newInteraction,
        dblclick: newInteraction
      },
      valueRange: [0, 150],
      legend: 'always',
      drawCallback: restyle,
      //rollPeriod: 1,
      //showRoller: true
    };

    // finally create the graph
    var flipped_dygraph = new Dygraph($(dygraph_div_id)[0], data, dygraph_options);
    // alter another mousemove function since we've rotated this graph 90 degrees
    flipped_dygraph.mousemove_func = flipped_dygraph.mouseMove_;
    flipped_dygraph.mouseMove_ = function (b) {
      // "b" is the MouseEvent object. Copy the object so we can edit it, since MouseEvent is read-only
      var new_b = jQuery.extend(true, {}, b);
      // switch the x and y values for this mouse event... well, dygraphs only cares about the mouse X value in this case.
      new_b.pageX = $(dygraph_div_id).width() + $(dygraph_div_id).offset().left - (b.pageY - $(dygraph_div_id).offset().top) - $(window).scrollLeft();
      // call the original function, using the new MouseEvent
      flipped_dygraph.mousemove_func(new_b);
    }

  }
```

```css
  div.graph {
    position: absolute;
  }


  /* rotate the 'rollPeriod' input box */
  .graph input {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: translateY(-8px) translateX(-9px) rotate(-90deg);
  }

  /* fix axis labels */
  .graph .dygraph-axis-label-y {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .graph .dygraph-axis-label-x {
    text-align: right;
  }

  .graph .dygraph-legend {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(10px) translateY(10px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(10x) translateY(10px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(30px) translateY(10px);
  }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.css" />
  <!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph.js"></script>-->
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/1.0.1/dygraph-combined.js"></script>
<!--      <script type="text/javascript" src="dc.js"></script>-->
  <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dygraph.css"/>-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div style="margin: 50px 0 0 50px;">
  <div id="graph" class="graph"></div>
</div>
```